# как достать переменную из функции?

Tags: javascript

Привет. 
Если я создаю функцию

```js
function qwe() {
  var x=10;
  console.log(x);
}

qwe();
```

то как можно достать переменную `x`? Когда функция отрабатывает (если брэйкпоинт поставить), то можно достать - написать в консоли `x`; При этом, если я пишу `window.x;` - будет уже `undefined`, хотя записи `x;` и `window.x;` значат одно и то же.

Что такое execution context?Напишите, пожалуйста, своими словами - как сами понимаете. как execution context соотносится со scope (областью видимости)? это разные вещи или нет?

Comment: вернуть, например. `return x`  в конце функции.

Comment: _хотя записи x; и window.x; значат одно и то же_ — это очевидная глупость и неправда.

Comment: ничего здесь очевидного нет

Comment: Если в функции ты объявишь переменную `x` без ключевого словa `var`, то есть просто: `x = 10;`, то `x` окажется в глобальной области видимости.

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, никак. Переменные, объявленные внутри функции, доступны только внутри неё и внутри вложенных функций (через замыкание).

> если я пишу `window,x;`

Запятая? Синтаксически корректно, но это не то, что ты хочешь написать. Вероятно ты хочешь точку. Но это всё равно не заработает. `x` и `window.x` значат одно и то же ( да и то не совсем) только если в текущем скоупе не была объявлена переменная с именем `x`. А в твоём коде она объявлена была.

Comment: вместо точки запятую поставил. хотел написать window.x;

Comment: что такое скоуп? и чем он отличается от исполняемого контекста?

Comment: @Dimon, доступные переменные. Контекст - вроде как `this`. Хотя есть ещё несколько контекстов. Непринципиально.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, execution context - это какой-то объект. так пишут в статьях

Comment: C терминологией надо разбираться. Стандарт описывает как объект - да. Но доступа извне к нему нет.